# Commented code that is still displayed on the site

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from basketball-reference.com and I have noticed that parts of the source file that are commented out actually are displayed on the website.

Here's the link to the site:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html

view-source:https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html

There are different categories of statistics displayed in a table, but for some reason only the "Per Game" category is not actually commented out, see part starting from line 864 is where the actual data is contained.
For the other categories the tags containing the data are all commented out, see e.g. line 1191 for the "Total" category or line 1278 for the "Per 36 Minutes" category.

I'm using scrapy and there is no way in xpath to extract any tags from commented code.

Can someone tell me how the code is still being displayed on the site and 
whether it's possible to extract tags from comments in XPath?

Comment: It is possible that it is written to the page using JS. If so, there are probably subtle differences between the commented-out code and the actually-used code. Most scrapers would not run JS before scraping, but Chrome Headless (or Selenium WebDriver) would.

Comment: However, if it is written using JS, then the data you want probably exists in a JS variable in one of the scripts, or is loaded as a separate AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if that were the case, what would be the rationale for including the code for the one category, but no the others?

Comment: Just a heads up: what you are doing is expressly against their terms of service: *You may not frame, capture, harvest, or collect any part of the Site or Content without SRL's advance written consent.*.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however, I have read their use of data terms: https://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.html, in which it says: "We will not fulfill any requests for data for custom downloads, unless you are prepared to pay a minimum of $1,000 for any such request.

We realize this will be insurmountable for any student requests. However, I would point out that learning how to accumulate data is often a more valuable skill than actually analyzing the data, so we encourage you as a student or professional to learn how. "

Comment: I won't be using the data for commercial purposes, nor will I scrape the site excessively.

Comment: @Eager I have no idea. Rationale is not really something we can guess.

Comment: @eager2learn I'm not familiar with `scrapy`, but with [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) you could parse those tables with `xidel -s https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html -e '//comment() ! parse-html(.)//div[@class="table_outer_container"]'`